# XQuery: How to convert string into XPath rules

Tags: xpath, xquery

The following is a simple XQuery that would run an xpath against an htm file and return how many matching tags were found. The xpath rules are in variable $rule, but I would like to use the string variable $rule-unused instead. How can I convert this string into a node-set and have it run against my document similar to the  $document//$rule ?

```
    xquery version "3.1";

    declare namespace persons="http://www.test.com/test/profiles";
    declare variable $uri as xs:string := "/db/apps/Persons/profile.htm";
    declare variable $rule-unused as xs:string := "//persons:relationship";

    let $document := doc($uri)
    let $rule := //persons:relationship
    let $all-lines := $document//$rule
    return
    <test>
        {
            count( $all-lines )
        }
    </test>
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to achieve but in general dynamic evaluation of paths or queries in a string needs a proprietary extension so check your XQuery processor's documentation for an `eval` or similar function. Of course simple searches like the one your show where you seem to simply want to check for a certain element name might work with e.g. `//*[name() = $name]` (with e.g. `$name := 'persons:relationship'`).

Comment: Thanks. Basically, the objective is to count how many of a specific tag exists in the given htm file. In this example,  this XQuery counts all `<persons:relationship>` tags in profile.htm. However, we would like to read this XPath rule from another XML file in string format.

Comment: As I said, look into proprietary extensions of your XQuery processor, neither XQuery 1 nor XQuery 3 have something standardized I think, except that in theory (or in case of combined XSLT and XQuery implementations like Saxon in practice) you can use the `fn:transform` function to run an XSLT stylesheet using `xsl:evaluate` to evaluate a path. But in general its proprietary and namespaces complicate life, as in many cases.

Comment: Also, consider using higher-order functions in place of dynamically-constructed expressions. For example, `let $rule := function($e){boolean($e/self::person)} return count(//*[$rule(.)]`.